# How do you change a div attribute class to multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html, class, button

Hi this is my first post here.

I'm trying to create a button or clickable hyperlink that will cause a chat-window (live-chat support) to come up.  The chat window comes up when you click on it's buttons, but I want to create a separate "click here" link to control it as well.  How do I change a div's class attributes where it contains multiple class.  I tried the following code below, but it's a no go for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#jivo-label").removeClass("jivo-fixed-right jivo-animate jivo-online jivo-fade-in").addClass("jivo-fixed-right jivo-animate jivo-online");
    $("#jivo-phantom").removeClass("jivo-right jivo-phantom-label jivo-notransition").addClass("jivo-right jivo-phantom-chat");
    $("#jivo-chat").removeClass("jivo-animated jivo-online").addClass("jivo-animated jivo-online jivo-fade-in");
    document.getElementById('jivo_chat_iframe').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('jivo_chat_iframe').style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

Comment: You are missing: `});`

Comment: .addClass() and .removeClass() should do the trick.  What is not working for you?

Comment: I don't understand. You appear to be removing classes and then immediately adding them back in. I think you are confused by the syntax, but it's not clear what you want. What exactly are you trying to accomplish in your function?

Comment: show us your HTML code - this code doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add

```
)};
```

to the end of your code. It's missing it. Secondly, to add classes, use

```
.addClass();
```

to add a class to a give selected tag or group of tags. It takes an argument of the class name to be added (in the form of a string) between the parentheses.The same is true of

```
.removeClass();
```

but it removes the given class. As an example, to add the class of "active" to a div with the ID "div1", you would do

```
$("#div1").addClass('active');
```

and to remove it

```
$("#div1").removeClass('active');
```

so using these, write a function, create the link you want, and then call the function on the click of the link, which would be achieved by this: say your function is called 'clickLink()'. Let's pretend that the link's id is 'link1'. Write this code:

```
$('#link1').click(function(){
 clickLink();
});
```

Put the code you need [utilizing the .addClass() and .removeClass()] in the function clickLink(), and MAKE SURE TO DEFINE THE FUNCTION IN THE SCRIPT FILE BEFORE YOU CALL IT. If you have any questions, post a comment and I'll answer as best I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#jivo-label").removeClass("jivo-fixed-right jivo-animate jivo-online jivo-fade-in")
        $("#jivo-label").addClass("jivo-fixed-right jivo-animate jivo-online");
        $("#jivo-phantom").removeClass("jivo-right jivo-phantom-label jivo-notransition")
        $("#jivo-phantom").addClass("jivo-right jivo-phantom-chat");
        $("#jivo-chat").removeClass("jivo-animated jivo-online")
        $("#jivo-chat").addClass("jivo-animated jivo-online jivo-fade-in");
        document.getElementById('jivo_chat_iframe').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('jivo_chat_iframe').style.visibility = 'visible';
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also check your logic, you are removing some classes and adding them back on the same event.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) is what you need. For example,

```
$(function(){
    //bind click on button and link
    $("button, .click-me-link").click(function(){
        //add classes if they were not present and remove them otherwise
        $('.your-popup').toggleClass('visible animated'); 
    });
})
```

And one more, if you are using jQuery you can simply write

```
$('#jivo_chat_iframe').css({'display':'block'});
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('jivo_chat_iframe').style.display = 'block';
```

If you want just to show/hide iframe then the best solution will be:

```
$(function(){
    //bind click on button and link
    $("button, .click-me-link").click(function(){
        //show|hide iframe
        $('#jivo_chat_iframe').toggle(); 
    });
})
```

See [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).